# Linear combination of a string vector (w/functions) and number vector (coefficients)

Tags: matlab

I'm really new at matlab, and am trying to fit a line or curve to data points for homework (that part is actually done). Now, I want to take this a little further than the homework asked, I have constructed a function that takes in a text file with coordinates and any number of functions (`1,x,x^2...` e.g.) and determines the coefficients.

So in the end I'm left with two vectors: one with the coefficients: `C = [a,b,c]` and another one with functions: `F = {'1','x','x^2'}`, and I'd like to create a linear combination of them: `l = a + b*x + c*x^2`, to plot the curve on a graph, and for some reason I can't figure out how to get that to work. Is there something obvious I'm overlooking, or do I have to rethink this in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=1; b=2; c=3;
C=[a,b,c];
CS = cellfun(@num2str,num2cell(C),'uniformoutput',0)
M={'*','*','*'};
F={'1','x','x^2'};
P={' + ',' + ',''};
S=reshape([CS; M; F; P],1,[]);
cat(2,S{:})
```

Output:

```
ans =

1*1 + 2*x + 3*x^2
```

Are you sure you want to print 'a', 'b' and 'c' as chars?

Comment: This is what I thought of soon, the problem is I get the error ??? Error using ==> dot at 30
A and B must be same size, and I'm guessing it has something to do with the type of the vectors. The first one has numbers, the second one has been converted from cell() to char()..

Comment: Did you mean F={'1','x','x^2'} ? Do you plan to use the symbolic toolbox?

Comment: Yes to the first question, the second point I don't exactly understand right now, but I'm going to read up on it and come back.

Comment: Ah, no.. Isn't it possible to do this somehow using inline()?

Comment: No, those were just meant to represent some coefficients, in my code those are numbers. I'm going to try the solution